# For-loop vs while loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, floating-point, while-loop

I have noticed a curious thing whilst working in R.
When I have a simple program that computes squares from 1 to N implemented using for-loop and while-loop the behaviour is not the same. (I don't care about vectorisation in this case or apply functions).

```
fn1 <- function (N) 
{
    for(i in 1:N) {
        y <- i*i
    }
}
```

AND

```
fn2 <- function (N) 
{
    i=1
    while(i <= N) {
        y <- i*i
        i <- i + 1
    }
}
```

The results are:

```
system.time(fn1(60000))
   user  system elapsed 
  2.500   0.012   2.493 
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
Warning messages:
1: In i * i : NAs produced by integer overflow
.
.
.

system.time(fn2(60000))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.138   0.000   0.137
```

Now we know that for-loop is faster, my guess is because of pre allocation and optimisations there. But why does it overflow?

UPDATE: So now trying another way with vectors:

```
fn3 <- function (N) 
{
    i <- 1:N
    y <- i*i
}
system.time(fn3(60000))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.008   0.000   0.009 
Warning message:
In i * i : NAs produced by integer overflow
```

So Perhaps its a funky memory issue? I am running on OS X with 4Gb of memory and all default settings in R. This happens in 32- and 64-bit versions (except that times are faster).

Alex

Comment: Based on your timing while-loop is faster.

Comment: when you convert the counter in the for loop to a float it will be faster than the while loop but it's only because the for loop then has no warnings.

Comment: R is full of this sort of nonsense.

Comment: Good question, though.  I like the performance analysis.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Because `1` is numeric, but not integer (i.e. it's a floating point number), and `1:6000` is numeric and integer.

```
> print(class(1))
[1] "numeric"
> print(class(1:60000))
[1] "integer"
```

60000 squared is 3.6 billion, which is NOT representable in signed 32-bit integer, hence you get an overflow error:

```
> as.integer(60000)*as.integer(60000)
[1] NA
Warning message:
In as.integer(60000) * as.integer(60000) : NAs produced by integer overflow
```

3.6 billion is easily representable in floating point, however:

```
> as.single(60000)*as.single(60000)
[1] 3.6e+09
```

To fix your `for` code, convert to a floating point representation:

```
function (N)
{
    for(i in as.single(1:N)) {
        y <- i*i
    }
}
```

Comment: is that why seq(N) is preferred over 1:N ?

Comment: @Marek: Thought so too, but that gives an integer vector. Exactly what we didn't want. seq(1,N,1) gives a numeric vector.

Comment: @David : it's a matter of choice. Both are equivalent, and both give a vector of integers. seq(1,N,1) is the equivalent of as.single(1:N). See the answer of Spacedman as well.

Answer (score 4):

The variable in the for loop is an integer sequence, and so eventually you do this:

```
> y=as.integer(60000)*as.integer(60000)
Warning message:
In as.integer(60000) * as.integer(60000) : NAs produced by integer overflow
```

whereas in the while loop you are creating a floating point number.

Its also the reason these things are different:

```
> seq(0,2,1)
[1] 0 1 2
> seq(0,2)
[1] 0 1 2
```

Don't believe me?

```
> identical(seq(0,2),seq(0,2,1))
[1] FALSE
```

because:

```
> is.integer(seq(0,2))
[1] TRUE
> is.integer(seq(0,2,1))
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: But why would floating points have larger range than integers?

Comment: UPDATE: "Note that on almost all implementations of R the range of representable integers is restricted to about +/-2*10^9: doubles can hold much larger integers exactly." From R documentation for integer :(

Comment: @Alex (not Brown): an integer is a binary representation in 32bits. So the maximum range is 2^32, or ~ [-2e9, +2e9]. A floating point uses the 32 bits different : it saves a number of bits for the digits (where the decimal is after the first digit), and another set of bits for the power. Obviously this makes the range very much larger. This is general computing knowledge by the way, apart from some small details this system is the same in every computer language / application.

Answer (score 3):

And about timing:

```
fn1 <- function (N) {
    for(i in as.numeric(1:N)) { y <- i*i }
}
fn2 <- function (N) {
    i=1
    while (i <= N) {
        y <- i*i
        i <- i + 1
    }
}

system.time(fn1(60000))
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.06    0.00    0.07 
system.time(fn2(60000))
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.12    0.00    0.13
```

And now we know that for-loop is faster than while-loop. You cannot ignore warnings during timing.

Comment: This is still not fully fair since while loop have larger body; this is necessary to emulate for, I know, but in some problems this is not the case.

Comment: @mbq That why for-loop and while-loop cannot be compare. Each has different purpose. You can add `i<-i+1` line in `fn1` but it's still be faster cause `fn2` has to check condition, which means 60k calls to `<=`. If you add another line `i<=N` to `fn1` then timings are equal.